# Converting an uml class diagram to c# code

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, uml, class-diagram

I have this UML diagram:

[image]

I have tried to convert it to C# code:

```
internal class Task:Organizer
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }

        private bool done=false;

        public  bool Done 
        {
            get { return done; }
            set { done = value;}
        }
```

Is this how it's supposed to look like?

Comment: No, this diagram does not show inheritance, but composition.

Comment: You are missing the `Organizer` class. You are missing the `Task` constructor. You are missing the `PrintTask()` method. The relation between `Task` and `Organizer` is wrong. It's an aggregation, i.e. `Organizer` _has_ 0 to _n_ task and each `Task` has 1 `Organizer`. So you need an additional member reflecting the relation from `Task` to `Organizer`. But there is no sensible way of doing that, because that UML is bullpoop.

Comment: If you wanna make your instructor uncomfortable then ask them how that little `1` on the relation between `Task` and `Organizer` should be represented with code.

Comment: @KlausGütter shared aggregation.  Composition (aka composite aggregation) would be with a black diamond ;-)

Comment: no I am not missing them, I just posted a part of my code because StackOverflow didnt allow me to post all the code, so how can I reflect the relation from Task to Organizer with a member variable, should it be inside the Organizer class?

Comment: Bleibt bitte beim Englischen. This is supposed to be read by people who do not speak German (like us).

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not supposed to look like this:  `Task:Organizer` is  inheritance in C#.  In UML it would be represented as follows:

[image]

This would be obviously wrong, because your diagram does not express inheritance but shared aggregation.

Bu the way, your input diagram seems not correct. It uses an association with the shared aggregation symbol (white diamond) on the wrong side. The corrected version would look like:

[image]

But since the aggregation does not add any semantic, the rest of my answer is valid also for the incorrect input diagram. The diagram could as well use a simple association without diamond and have exactly the same implementation.

To implement this, you need to create two classes,  `Organizer` and `Task` with a collection of `Task` as property of `Organizer`.

```
class Task
{
    ...
}

class Organizer
{
    ...
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: He's asking how to make the C-stuff from the diagram, not vice versa. So _Your input diagram seems not correct_ can't be a valid answer.

Comment: but the Tasks is underlined red for me , how should I correct that ?

Comment: @qwerty_so ok,  I've updated my answer:  since shared aggregation doesn't change semantic,  I can just ignore it,  and don't worry about the wrong diagram.  Nevertheless,  I feel compelled to highlight that there is an issue in the diagram, so that student do not learn wrong syntax.

Comment: @nino Your original code has a missing closing curly brace.  Maybe in your real code there are additional syntax errors.  You can have a look here a skeleton, without anything in red:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q0Y0sI

Comment: @Christophe thanks for the skeleton, but there are two compilation errors

Comment: Well, who knows! This is a Mickeysoft created diagram and as such wrong per se ;-) I guess the OP got this from someone who wasn't fluent in UML either. Probably as a lesson. And we all know how bad teachers are in that respect. Keeps us creating one answer after the other... Oh, es ist eine Schulaufgabe xD

Comment: @qwerty_so (Tja! Ich glaube, wir könnten ein Klassendiagram der Schulaufgaben erstellen ;-) - Yes, homework and bad teachers force us to preach the UML truth, again and again. But it is to contribute to a better world and a better communication. So vested bybthis mission, we should just go on :-D